# CSS relative element obstructs float

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

**Code:**

```html
<style>
div {
  width: 500px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}

ul > li {
   position: relative;
}

ul > li:before {
  content: "\2022";
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: inherit;
  left: -0.75em;
}
</style>
<div>
<span style="float:right"><a href="http://google.com">Test link</a><br/>
<a href="http://google.com">Test link</a><br/>
<a href="http://google.com">Test link</a><br/>
<a href="http://google.com">Test link</a><br/>
<a href="http://google.com">Test link</a></span>
<ul>
<li>The <a href="http://google.com">glowing steel</a> is extremely hot and will harm anyone that touches it. Jumping into the slag bucket is an instant death, regardless of [[Damage Threshold]].</li>
<li>The ''"Lucky 38 Executive Override"'' option on the terminal on the second level was originally supposed to be part of the quest [[The Moon Comes Over the Tower]], but that section was cut. See that quest's notes section for details.</li>
<li>The three Mr. Steels found inside, as well as the fiends, respawn every three game days.</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In the above example links are inaccessible. Is this an intended CSS behavior? Are there any proper fixes?

**So far I came up with few inferior solutions:**

1. Make all float elements `position:relative` and `z-index:1`: *Obviously not a good general solution.*
2. `Overflow:hidden` on `ul` element: *Links are accessible, but list elements stop wrapping around the float.*
3. `Overflow:hidden` on `li` element: *Links are accessible, list elements wrapping around the float. But `:before` content becomes invisible.*
4. `z-index: -1` on `li` elements: Links in floats become accessible in exchange of links in the list becoming inaccessible.

And, after some further thought I ended up on giving all `:link` elements `position:relative` and `z-index:1`. Not ideal obviously, but I guess it's the one with least drawbacks so far.

Comment: just don't use float - there are always problems with it  and display: inline-block most of the time achieves the same effect

Comment: How do you achieve the float effect with `display:inline-block`?

Comment: inline-block puts elements on the same line just like float

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't cut it.

Comment: @Scott Selby: If it achieves the same effect "most of the time" as you claim, this isn't one of those times. For one thing, the definition of "line" is very different between inline-block and float, considering one happens on an IFC and one happens on a BFC.

Answer (score 2):

Can you wrap all your links in a div and set that wrapper with this style:

```
.link-wrapper{
   position:relative;
   z-index:9;
}
```

Like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxzxhh4g/).

**UPDATE**

Another possible solution might be to set you `z-index` of your `<li>`'s to something below 0. Like this:

```
ul > li {
   position: relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3pop66pz/).

**UPDATE 2**

Here is another possible solution that involves setting a negative margin and using a transform for your `:before` content. It is a bit hacky but I *might* work in your situtation.

Add these styles:

```
ul > li:before {
  display:inline-block;
   margin-left:-20px;
   margin-right:10px;
   transform:translateY(5px);
}
```

And remove this style:

```
ul > li {
    position:relative;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c8juf5c/1/).

Comment: This solution is already mentioned in the OP. If it was a just a single case, but the web site in question has too many possible float elements to account for.

Comment: @Slider2k Sorry I do not see a solution that involves wrapping the floats in a div, just one that suggests changing the floats to `position:relative;`. Anyways I have an updated answer, let me know if that works. Thanks

Comment: With `z-index:-1` on `li`, links in list elements stop working.

Comment: In my case wrapping floats won't help as the pages don't have pre-defined layouts, but are instead generated.

Comment: @Slider2k I have provided another possible solution. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Update 2 is interesting. Thanks. (*I'd give you +1 for effort, but I'm not able yet.*)